# Is it possible to call a method from within an ArrayList of type Class?

Tags: java, eclipse, methods, arraylist, processing

I have an ArrayList of class `public ArrayList<Spheres> sphereList = new ArrayList<Spheres>(10);` and I need to call a method from within class `Spheres` to update all of the elements in `sphereList`. Is that possible, and if so, how would I go about doing that? And if its not possible, is there an alternative approach that I should be taking?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Where is your `sphereList` defined, in which class?

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by calling method from within a class? Or it would be good of you to provide pseudo code example and your expectations from it.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with the Processing language? If not, it should not have the [tag:processing] tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sphereList.stream().forEach(x -> x.callMethodFromSphere());
```

Answer (score 0):

Anything's possible...

-You would have to pass references from the parent class into each instance of Spheres

-Or use an Observer - Observable design pattern

-Or change your ArrayList into a LinkedList that updates the chain of references when a method is invoked.